# Multiple custom cells in one table view not working

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a table view that I want to display two different custom cells; however, it is only displaying the first custom cell and nothing else.

```
class messageThreadViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if section == 0 {
            return finalItems.count
        } else {
            return finalItems2.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {           
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "message1") as! MyTableViewCellThread
            cell.messagelabel?.text = finalItems[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "message2") as! MyTableViewCellThread2
            cell2.messageLabel2?.text = finalItems2[indexPath.row]
            return cell2
       }
    }
}
```

Again, it's only displaying "cell", not both "cell" and "cell2". I've done a lot of research and couldn't find someone with the same issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure `finalItems2` is not empty?

Comment: replace `indexPath.section` with `indexPath.row` in func `cellforRowAt`,
set `numberOfRowsInSection` : 2 and `numberOfSections` : 1

Comment: furthermore make sure that you've registered both tableviewcells in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: @Deitsch yes it is not empty- I'm able to get either one or the other to show, not both.

Comment: @DimitrisDelis I apologize because this may not have been clear- numberOfRowsInSection varies based off the contents of "finalItems" and "finalItems2" so I can't set it to 2. Also I am using the interface builder so I have the cells registered on the storyboard. I will update the post avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

method

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

is not part of UITableViewDelegate and not called when tableView building ui

the right method to use is

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return finalItems.count
    } else {
        return finalItems2.count
        
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more? does this replace "func numberOfSectionsInTableView"? do I have to add "numberOfSections section: Int" to define "section"?

Comment: Yes use it to replace numberOfSectionsInTableView

Comment: @psettle41 numberOfSectionsInTableView method that you're using is not a part of UITableViewDelegate protocol and not called when table is building

Comment: @Kstin thank you for the help, this got it to work!